# Why does an iterator variable need to be mutable

Tags: rust, iterator

I am a newcomer to the rust scene. Still learning the in n outs of ownership, borrowing, lifetimes etc. Been working with NodeJS my whole career.

```
use battery::Manager;
use spin_sleep::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;
fn main() {
    loop {
        if let Ok(manager) = Manager::new() {
            if let Ok(batteries) = manager.batteries() {
//                    ^^^^^^^^^ - This variable
//Rust analyzer tells me to make it mutable and it is fixed when I do so
                if let Some(Ok(battery)) = batteries.next() {
                    println!("Vendor: {:?}", battery.vendor());
                    println!("Model: {:?}", battery.model());
                    println!("State: {:?}", battery.state());
                    println!("Charge: {:?}", battery.state_of_charge());
                    println!("Time to full charge: {:?}", battery.time_to_full());
                    println!("");
                }
            }
        }
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(180));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time you call `batteries.next()`, you get a different values (or `None` when it's finished).

This is because the iterator has an internal state, which can for example be an index in a referenced collection.

Calling `next` changes this internal state, which means the iterator has to be muted.

Comment: Ok, so batteries is an iterator and since iterator changes its state, it has to be mutable, but the value it gives is not mutable since it is a reference right?

Comment: The signature of the `next` method is: `fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>`. It requires `&mut self`, but you are giving it `&self`.  Specifying the `batteries` variable as mutable with `mut batteries` will give you the type of reference that the `next` method requires.

Comment: @tomas This isn't about the values returned by the iterator (which could be mutable references with an IterMut) but about the iterator. `manager.batteries()` returns an iterator and this iterator has to be mutable to call `next()`.